# Saving images to Rackspace with paperclip/cloudfiles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, paperclip, cloudfiles

I have my rails app filled with about 30000 products from various suppliers. Currently each product image_url is being hosted by individual suppliers. How would I go about saving each image from the image_url to my rackspace account, and make sure that each image_url generated by rackspace is assigned to the correct product.

Answer (score 0):

You could put this in a Rake task if you already have all the files and know which objects they should be associated with.

For each product,

1. Upload the image
2. Change the `image_url`
3. Validate the upload + the model name
4. Save the model

If you need to keep track of which are processed or not, you could either add a field in the model, or keep an array of processed Models until the task is complete.

Comment: (It's not clear if you need explicit instructions for using paperclip / cloudfiles.)